# How to take a list of objects and join them on a query in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Due to policies and users being on two different databases, I cannot add where clauses to my "includes" statements (throws table doesn't exist error due to the way AR constructs a single query instead of using different queries).  I can do `Policies :belongs_to Users` and then when I do `Policies.active.state('NY).includes(:users)` I also get the user associated with that poicy, but i cannot do `Policies.active.state('NY').includes(:users).where(users: {status_code: 'A'})` because it throws the table does not exist error on users (in the other database).

So what I want to do is be able to take the results from:

```
policies = Policies.active.state('NY').includes(:users)
```

and throw out the policies that do not contain users returned from:

```
Users.where(status_code: 'A')
```

and if the query could only be execuited against the users that return from the first query,that would be best

Comment: Have you tried `Policies.active.state('NY').where(users: Users.where(status_code: 'A'))`?

Comment: @UriAgassi Throws connection not established error

Comment: That does not seem to be related to the problem you describe - do both rows in the OP run correctly?

Comment: @UriAgassi yes, both run correctly, but what is happening is that the Users query is trying to use the connection that was established by the Policies query (AKA wrong database)

Comment: How is the relation implemented in the Policies database?

Comment: Why are they in two different databases?